# how to partition Activity in 3 parts for different Controls

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#16A180"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/scrol" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/lock" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/centertext" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is My Screen currently looking Like this .http://snag.gy/kwjAn.jpg i have to make of layout 3 partition vertically first for Google map ,Second for Name Display and , Third one for chat window actually i have make lay Out like this 10 part divide in to 4:2:4  3segement http://snag.gy/exrsu.jpg like this Layout. please help am unable to do this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#16A180"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/contact_btnLogout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_relMainHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

 </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="#000000"
        >

 </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="#ffff00"
        >

 </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) will help you get the desired result. I can explain to you the logic without writing the code(...you need to put that effort). Your layout should have 3 fragments

1. The mapfagment can be at the top. [Mapfragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html)
2. This can be followed by the fragment that contains a textview.
3. And the last one will contain your chat window.